# PopupMenu inside Adapter getView() not working

Tags: android, listview, adapter, popupmenu

I'm using a custom adapter and adding this code on getView() method:

```
final ImageView popupMenu = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.popupMenu);
    popupMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            popupMenu.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_popup_menu_selected);
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(PopupMenu pm) {
                    popupMenu.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_popup_menu);
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
});
```

But I get this error: 
    `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6`

The same code works onListItemClick() but it doesn't make sense to be there because it needs to be clicked once to setup and click again to trigger the PopupMenu.

**Edit**: Logcat

```
11-02 17:58:51.276    1996-1996/com.android.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.example, PID: 1996
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6591)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:735)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:679)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:62)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper$MenuAdapter.getView(MenuPopupHelper.java:363)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.measureContentWidth(MenuPopupHelper.java:212)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:146)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:118)
        at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:168)
        at com.android.example.GetAdapter$listAdapter$1.onClick(GetAdapter.java:81)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat error?

Comment: GetAdapter.java:81 this line is where it crashed. what's at that line?

Comment: @GoranHoriaMihail popup.show();

Comment: yeah, it makes sense, you want to set up the event in getview() but show the popup in onListItemClick(). you are now trying to show the popup in getview(), which is wrong.

Comment: has that solved the issue?

Answer (score 5):

With the following import I always had the error:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
```

It works fine with the following import:

```
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
```

Full answer: [stackoverflow.com/a/27826670/4548500](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27826670/4548500)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this way:

Add this on adapter getView():

`ImageView popupMenu = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.popupMenu);
popupMenu.setTag(getItem(position));
popupMenu.setOnClickListener(MyFragment.popupMenuListener);`

And this on MyFragment:

`implements OnClickListener`

`popupMenuListener = this;`

`@Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showPopupMenu(view);
            }
        });
}`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to missing theme attributes.
Make sure that your app theme extends `Theme.AppCompat`.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
```