# Popup menu in fragment does not appear

Tags: android, menu, fragment, popupmenu, android-imagebutton

Fairly new to android, I'm currently having some difficulties implementing a `PopupMenu` on my `ImageButton` in a Fragment. There are no errors in the code, the emulator is able to build successfully but upon clicking the `ImageButton`, the popup menu does not show up.

OneFragment.java

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container,false);

    ImageButton popupButton = (ImageButton)rootview.findViewById(R.id.chineseTelevision);
    popupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), v);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_main);
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
  }
}
```

After applying Pavneet's solution (which is the right solution)

```
return rootview;
```

I stumbled onto another error,

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x486 "res/drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_material.xml" a=1 r=0x10803d6}
```

I found out that this error was caused android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.

This link has the solution but no explanation to why the widget caused the issue. Here [Popup Menu in custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782846/popup-menu-in-custom-listview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return the `rootview` instead of new one

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
```

so it should be

```
return rootview;
```

`return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);` will create and return a new view instead of, the one you have created and hence the new one will not have any initialized `popupmenu` object inside it

so your code will be

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container,false);

    ImageButton popupButton = (ImageButton)rootview.findViewById(R.id.chineseTelevision);

    popupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), v);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_main);
        popupMenu.show();

    }
  });
  return rootview;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I understand more which view to return now. The code did run without any errors but upon clicking the ImageButton, I have this error.


`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x486 "res/drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_material.xml" a=1 r=0x10803d6}`

Comment: it's something with resources , i tried your code and with my solution and it's working fine , just make sure your `theme` and `menu xml` files has no issue though seems like a `theme` issue to me , try clean and run

Comment: After some googling, I found out that the error after your solution was the popup widget issue. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782846/popup-menu-in-custom-listview) in case anyone gets the same issue as me. I have marked your solutions, thanks Paveneet.

Comment: @wuck i am very glad that you have done it ,keep it up :)

Answer (score 0):

For that problem actually I suggest you to manage the onclick from activity, you can create an interface that allows to propagate through the activity, is cleaner.